# How to go Next Activity directly after Login in facebook SDK 3.0 in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i am using facebook SDK 3.0 when i am login to facebook it come back to login screen than go to next Activity but i want to go directly to Next Activity.

This is my Code :-

```
if (session.isOpened()) {
        token = session.getAccessToken();
        Log.i("TAG", "Access Token" + token);
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        id = user.getId();
                        Log.i("TAG", "User ID " + user.getId());
                        Log.i("TAG", "Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));

                            try {
                                URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large" );
                                profPict=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());

                                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    //http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture

                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Next.class);
                                     i.putExtra("BitmapImage", profPict);  
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    // lblEmail.setText(user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                            }
                    }
            });
}
```

And `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);}
```

Comment: i am also looking for same :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey please instert the following code in the onActivityResult block:

```
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null || Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
                 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Next.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In `onActvityResult()`, check if result is `RESULT_OK`, if it is then start new activity.
I'm assuming you are not starting any other activity for result.

Refer this code - [FbLoginActivity](http://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5560725) This is just a skeleton that you can follow to login into facebook

You can also refer this-> [FbLoginButton](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton).

Comment: No i am not starting any other activity for result. i still am not getting.

Comment: Now i am using Like this but still not Working:             @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
    resultCode, data);                   
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Profil.class);
     i.putExtra("BitmapImage", profPict);  
     i.putExtra("id",id);
           i.putExtra("emailid",email_mail);
    startActivity(i);
        }

 }

Comment: did you debug the app & checked what is the value of resultCode?

Comment: value of resultCode is = -1 and control after coming back to Main Activity goes to next Activity without getting data.  plz advice me i need urgently

Comment: Okay...I hope you have registered SessionStatusCallback in your activity, so in your SessionStatusCallback, put the code which checks whether session is opened or not & if opened, then execute me request, and on completion of me request start the new activity.

Basically put the code which you posted in your question under SessionStatusCallback

Comment: @ Vishal Pawale i am not getting form this code and need urgent can u please help me ?

Comment: Ohhh sorry, my bad...that was for Sharing Post on Facebook,Refer this code - https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5560725
This is just a skeleton that you can follow to login into facebook.

Comment: You can also refer this-> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton

Comment: thanks vvvvery much sir!!!!its working now.i d'nt know how could i thanks u..thanks again...

Comment: but when i logout it is giving problum to again login:- i am using this code for logout:- private void logout(){
      Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
      session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
     // return the user to the login screen
     Toast.makeText(context,"Successfully Logedout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main1Activity.class));
     // make sure the user can not access the page after      finish();
 }

Comment: and it is going to else {

          Log.e("ELSEEEEEEE", "EMAILLLL");

          // Clear all session info & ask user to
          // login again
          Session session = Session
            .getActiveSession();
          if (session != null) {
           session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

          }
         }  of Login Activity any sugetion please?

Comment: Are you referring the code which is there on github? If yes, then change line no 50, I have changed it on github, you can refer it

BTW have to tried to login again?

Comment: yes sir i am refering code in github and line no. 50 is :-if(!session.isOpened()) { .. and i am replacing from old one :-&& !session.isClosed().

Comment: it's not working sir it is giving exception when i am loging again after logout.Exception is :--java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:947)..